# How to get breakpoints from Eclipse without using the debug plugin/framework

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

Say I want execute some custom Java code for when a user adds or removes a breakpoint. I know that the normal way is handle this within eclipse's org.eclipse.debug.core framework, but I am not currently doing that. I have a custom debugger which uses none of that, currently. Is there a way to to (1) listen for events of added and removed linebreaks and (2) gathering all current linebreak markers when eclipse is started (synchronizing them to the custom debugger) ?

Answer (score 0):

one way to do it is to get BreakpointsView and get it from there using reflection